# Others can't hear what I'm listening to during voice conversation on Windows Live Messenger

Tags: windows-7, audio, windows-live-messenger

When I'm on a voice or video call, the other person can't hear what I'm playing in Windows Media Player, or a podcast on a website. I have a Toshiba Satellite P200 running Windows 7  and Windows Live Messenger.

The video and audio are both working perfectly - it is just what I'm listening to at the same time that can't be heard.

Comment: Are you wearing headphones? Can the microphone pickup the speakers?

Comment: no, no headphones, just the computer speakers and mic.

Comment: Could there be some noise cancellation nonsense happening?

Comment: well i was checking on the adapter properties and windows live messenger setup,  and there is no noise cancelation options...

Comment: Have you tried a different media player?

Comment: yes, even with a web player.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding? Isn't the default behavior of the sound card NOT to route system output to whatever input?

Comment: well, some of my friends are able to do it :/ . It must be a driver option or something :/ . most of them are in vista.